# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000063: Unable to instantiate class

Tags: java, hibernate

I am running junit written in Custom JSR 303 Validation using ConstraintValidator. Something like this [example](http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.in/2013/05/custom-jsr-303-validation-using-constraintValidator.html)

My Validation test class:

```
public class ProductV2ValidationTest {
    private static Validator validator;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ExternalApiException {
         ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();  
         validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();  
   }

   @Test
   public void ValidatorTest() {
       try {
           ProductV2 productV2 = getObjectMapper().readValue(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/json/productV2Valid.json"),  ProductV2.class);

           Set<ConstraintViolation<ProductV2>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(productV2);  
          for(ConstraintViolation<ProductV2> constraintViolation : constraintViolations){  
            String message = constraintViolation.getMessage();  
            System.out.println(message);  
        }  

        assertEquals(0,constraintViolations.size());  

    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

}

FYI, My validators are in some another maven project(jar),and test are written in another maven project(war).

I am getting this error:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000063: Unable to instantiate class com.xyz.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.NumberOfObjectsValidater.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:54)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ReflectionHelper.run(ReflectionHelper.java:658)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ReflectionHelper.newInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:206)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:34)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:141)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:101)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
at com.rakuten.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.ProductV2ValidationTest.ValidatorTest(ProductV2ValidationTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance can not access a member of class com.rakuten.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.NumberOfObjectsValidater with modifiers ""
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:368)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:48)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ReflectionHelper.run(ReflectionHelper.java:658)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ReflectionHelper.newInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:206)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:34)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:141)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:101)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
at com.rakuten.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.ProductV2ValidationTest.ValidatorTest(ProductV2ValidationTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.executeTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:126)
at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
... 6 more
```

I tried adding

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But no help .

I am using this dependancy:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is that the hibernate validator cannot create a new instance of com.rakuten.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.NumberOfObjectsValidater because it does not have a public default constructor.

You should be able to reproduce the problem be executing the following code:

```
public static void test() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    try {
        com.rakuten.gep.itemwrapper.external.entities.validator.NumberOfObjectsValidater.class.newInstance();
    }
    catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
        throw e;
    }    
    catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**The solution would be to add public modifier to the constructor of NumberOfObjectsValidater**

Comment: Your test code indeed give me the same error. I added a constructor for test purposes and forgot to add a default constructor. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add "public" to class declaration

your code:

```
class NumberOfObjectsValidater implements ConstraintValidator<IpAddress, String>{
}
```

right code:

```
public class NumberOfObjectsValidater implements ConstraintValidator<IpAddress, String>{
        }
```